# Reading words from a file into dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, file, pointers, dynamic-arrays

So I am trying to read string data from a file into a dynamically allocated array, but I cannot seem to get the correct code for doing so. I have below a code using an array of a preset size but that would not be efficient, hence why I want to use dynamic memory allocation. I know I have to use pointers but I am fairly new to the concept so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

#define SIZE 100

using namespace std;

void loadData();

int main()
{
    loadData();
    return 0;
    {

        string fileName;
        std::string wordArray[SIZE];
        cout << "Please enter the name of the text file you want to process followed by '.txt': " << endl;
        cin >> fileName;

        ifstream dataFile(fileName);
        if (dataFile.fail()) {
            cerr << fileName << " could not be opened." << endl; //error message if file opening fails
            exit(-1);
        }
        while (!dataFile.eof()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                dataFile >> wordArray[I];
                for (std::string& s : wordArray) //this for loop transforms all the words in the text file into lowercase
                    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
                        [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
            }
        }
        dataFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about a `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: There have to be hundreds of examples in the internet. Is there something you have tried already?

Comment: Mandatory read: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: `return 0; ` on the second line of `main()` will cause the program to end. No sure why you put that there. I am also not sure what loadData() actually accomplishes since it does not have any parameters.

Comment: *I know I have to use pointers* -- No, you don't have to use pointers.  A `std::vector<std::string>` relieves you of having to use pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The [below](https://onlinegdb.com/AsNu7gUzr) program show how you can store the strings read from the input.txt file and store them in lowercase in a `std::vector`.

**Version 1**: Stores word by word(in lowercase) into the vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("input.txt");
    
    //create vector that will contain the words in the file in lowercase 
    std::vector<std::string> wordVec;
    
    std::string line, individualWord;
    
    if(inputFile)
    {
        while(std::getline(inputFile, line, '\n'))
        {
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            while(ss >> individualWord)//word by word
            {
                std::transform(individualWord.begin(), individualWord.end(), individualWord.begin(),
                [](unsigned char c)
                { return std::tolower(c); 
                    
                });
                
                wordVec.push_back(individualWord);
            }
            
        
            
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file could not be opened"<<std::endl;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    
    //lets print out the elements of the vector to check if elements are correctly stored in lowercase 
    for(const std::string &elem: wordVec)
    {
        std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of version 1 can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/AsNu7gUzr).

**Version 2**: Stores a complete single line(in lowercase) into the vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("input.txt");
    
    //create vector that will contain the words in the file in lowercase 
    std::vector<std::string> wordVec;
    
    std::string line;
    
    if(inputFile)
    {
        while(std::getline(inputFile, line, '\n'))
        {
            std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c)
            { return std::tolower(c); 
                
            });
            
            wordVec.push_back(line);
        
            
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file could not be opened"<<std::endl;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    
    //lets print out the elements of the vector to check if elements are correctly stored in lowercase 
    for(const std::string &elem: wordVec)
    {
        std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above(version 2) program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/5f4Wev6w7).

The **difference between** version 1 and 2 is that version 1 reads a complete line and then read *word by word* and store those words(in lowercase) into the `std::vector` while version 2 reads a complete line(which ends with '\n') and store that line(in lowercase) into the `std::vector`.

Comment: I am very sorry that I do not meet your expectations. I will try to improve myself and try to become more skilled in C++. Thank you for giving the hint that 3 or 4 statements for solving the problem maybe too complicated. I added an additional solution that only needs 2 statements. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime life could be easy. By using modern C++ elements, the implementation will be really simple in the end.

I am not so sure what I should explain for 3 lines of code. It is basically visible with the comments in the code.

Please see the first solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

int main() {

    // Open the input file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputStream{ "r:\\input.txt" }; inputStream) {

        // Define a vector and read all words from the file
        std::vector words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(inputStream), {});

        // Show result to the user
        std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }
}
```

---

Then next solution converts the word into lower case. So, I had to write 4 statements. Please see the below second solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

int main() {

    // Open the input file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputStream{ "r:\\input.txt" }; inputStream) {

        std::vector<std::string> words{};

        // Read all words from the file and convert to lower case
        std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(inputStream), {}, std::back_inserter(words), 
            [](std::string w) { for (char& c : w) c = std::tolower(c); return w; });

        // Show result to the user
        std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }
}
```

---

If data does not need to be stored, we can come up with a 2-statement version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

int main() {

    // Open the input file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputStream{ "r:\\input.txt" }; inputStream) {

        // Read all words from the file and convert to lower case and output it
        std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(inputStream), {}, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
            [](std::string w) { for (char& c : w) c = std::tolower(c); return w; });
    }
}
```

---

Sometime teachers want the students to learn dynamic memory management using pointers.

But the usage of pointers for owned memory is strongly discouraged. The `std::vector` has been invented for that reason over a decade ago.

Anyway, I will also show a solution using `new`. It works, but you should not use it.

```
int main() {

    // Open the input file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputStream{ "r:\\input.txt" }; inputStream) {

        // Do some initial allocation of memory
        std::string* words = new std::string[1]{};
        unsigned int numberOfAvaliableSlotsInDynamicArray{1};

        // Now we want to read words. We want also to count the words,so that we can allocate appropriate memory
        std::string word{};
        unsigned int wordCounter{};

        // Read all words in a loop
        while (inputStream >> word) {

            // Check, if we still have enough space in our dynamic array
            if (wordCounter >= numberOfAvaliableSlotsInDynamicArray) {

                // Oh, we are running out of space. Get more memory
                numberOfAvaliableSlotsInDynamicArray *= 2;
                std::string* temp = new std::string[numberOfAvaliableSlotsInDynamicArray]{};

                // Copy all existing data into new array
                for (unsigned int i{}; i < wordCounter; ++i)
                    temp[i] = words[i];

                // Delete old memory
                delete[] words;

                // And assign new storage to words
                words = temp;
            }
            // STore the recently read word at the end of the array
            words[wordCounter] = word;

            // Count words. Now we have one word more
            ++wordCounter;
        }
        // Now we have read all words from the file. Show output
        for (unsigned int i{}; i < wordCounter; ++i)
            std::cout << words[i] << '\n';

        // Release memory
        delete[] words;
    }
}
```

---

And even smart pointers, which shall be used as pointers if at all, are not nice.

Also the following should not be used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

int main() {

    // Open the input file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputStream{ "r:\\input.txt" }; inputStream) {

        // Do some initial allocation of memory
        std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> words = std::unique_ptr<std::string[]>(new std::string[1]);
        unsigned int numberOfAvaliableSlotsInDynamicArray{ 1 };

        // Now we want to read words. We want also to count the words,so that we can allocate appropriate memory
        std::string word{};
        unsigned int wordCounter{};

        // Read all words in a loop
        while (inputStream >> word) {

            // Check, if we still have enough space in our dynamic array
            if (wordCounter >= numberOfAvaliableSlotsInDynamicArray) {

                // Oh, we are running out of space. Get more memory
                numberOfAvaliableSlotsInDynamicArray *= 2;

                std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> temp = std::unique_ptr<std::string[]>(new std::string[numberOfAvaliableSlotsInDynamicArray]);

                // Copy all existing data into new array
                for (unsigned int i{}; i < wordCounter; ++i)
                    temp[i] = std::move(words[i]);

                // And assign new storage to words
                words = std::move(temp);
            }
            // STore the recently read word at the end of the array
            words[wordCounter] = word;

            // Count words. Now we have one word more
            ++wordCounter;
        }
        // Now we have read all words from the file. Show output
        for (unsigned int i{}; i < wordCounter; ++i)
            std::cout << words[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**: Use a `std::vector`.